# Error building virtualbox guest additions for openSUSE 13.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running openSUSE 13.1 guest OS inside virtualbox on ubuntu 12.04 host. The OS installed fine, but when I try to build the guest addons by issuing "./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run", the build process fails as logged in vboxadd-install.log below. I have installed all dependencies including make, gcc and kernel-source:

vbox-install.log output

```
grep: /lib/modules/3.11.6-4-default/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/3.11.6-4-default/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
make -C /usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4-obj/i386/default \
KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4 \
KBUILD_EXTMOD="/tmp/vbox.0" -f /usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/Makefile \
modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                            \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";        \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";    \
echo >&2 ;                            \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f /usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.8/include -I/usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/include -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/vbox.0 -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i586 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h   -I/lib/modules/3.11.6-4-default/build/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/include   -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_X86  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuest_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_VBoxGuest-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c
/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:206:49: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘g_VBoxGuestPciId’
 static const struct pci_device_id __devinitdata g_VBoxGuestPciId[] =
                                                 ^
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:78:0,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:28:
/usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/include/linux/module.h:87:32: error: ‘__mod_pci_device_table’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘g_VBoxGuestPciId’
 extern const struct gtype##_id __mod_##gtype##_table  \
                                ^
/usr/src/linux-3.11.6-4/include/linux/module.h:140:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_GENERIC_TABLE’
   MODULE_GENERIC_TABLE(type##_device,name)
   ^
/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:216:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE’
 MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, g_VBoxGuestPciId);
 ^
make[4]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [vboxguest] Error 2
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this error is caused by the linux headers being out of sync with your kernel. You will have to download a newer version of the linux headers. I do not have an OpenSUSE pc at hand, but I seem to remeber that the headers are located in the *linux-glibc-devel * package.